# I used iframe in ios webview app to load a site, but the window is open

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview

In ios webview app, iframe was used to load the site, but a window open occurred.

For example, I imported a google page as an iframe, but when I go to safari, a google page pops up, and within the app, it pops up except for the iframe.

Current development is swift, and when using javascript and html iframe I get the above error.

Comment: got any solution for this